# What is the system-provided certificate database (Python PEP 476)?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, pep

Extract from PEP 476:

> This PEP proposes using the system-provided certificate database. Previous discussions have suggested bundling Mozilla's certificate database and using that by default.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/#trust-database

What is meant by the *system-provided certificate database*?